# Issue while reciveing an answer in scapy

Tags: scapy

When I tried to use the `sr1` command in `scapy` with packets, it sends the packet but it didn't receive the reply.

For example, I tried to send a `ping` packet with the `sr1` in order to receive the reply. I have seen the request-packet in `wireshark` but nearby was written `"response not found"` while the reply packet was just 2 lines down.

Comment: Is this only happening for `ICMP`? Please try to provide a non-zero `ICMP.id` to your `echo-request`

Comment: No... My problem is with the sr1 command ,not only icmp , sr1 is waiting for a packet , but doesn't recive it.(although the packet arrived to my computer)

Comment: please provide (edit) os/distri, scapy version, network layout (NAT?,VM?), sample code - otherwise this is just fortunetelling.

Comment: For example , there is a link for a print screen of my screen while I tried to run the sr1 command --- https://gyazo.com/6c7d4dd4fad4e653a1726435191e889a